# React Native (Expo) app — need to parse RSS feed to find url for img src

Tags: javascript, react-native, rss, html-parsing

I have a React Native app which I'm using Expo.

I'm using the library `react-native-rss-parser` to parse xml rss feeds and return as json. It works well for the most part.

However, the json returned does not return an thumbnail or image url.

There is a field called "content" and it looks like this:

```
content: "<figure><img src='https://d36tnp772eyphs.cloudfront.net/blogs/1/2020/06/Black-Lives-Matter-protest-on-Alexanderplatz-Berlin.jpg' class='webfeedsFeaturedVisual'></figure><p><span style="text-transform:uppercase;">Protests sparked by</span> the murder of George Floyd <a href="https://matadornetwork.com/read/george-floyd-protests-worldwide/" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">haven’t just been contained to the United States</a>. This weekend, what is believed to be the largest turnout of Black Lives Matter protesters outside of the US took place in Germany. Over 15,000 protesters gathered in Alexanderplatz, in Berlin’s city center, in acknowledgment that racial discrimination..."
```

How do I parse this and get the `img` `src` url? I really just need to go grab this from `content`:

> https://d36tnp772eyphs.cloudfront.net/blogs/1/2020/06/Black-Lives-Matter-protest-on-Alexanderplatz-Berlin.jpg

I've tried different React Native HMTL parsers and regex and nothing is quite working...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you adding a simple regex rule

```
https.*?.jpg
```

Find a [regex example](https://regexr.com/5soue)